# Excel Integration- How to append a dataframe in a specific range of cells with python Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I´m trying to append a pandas dataframe into a xlsm file using the Openpyxl module of Python.
The problem is that i get write on the excel file, but just on the first column, but i want to write on the blank spaces of that excel.
Could anyone point out where my syntax is incorrect?
Below is an image of the table and my python code

[image: excel table]

```python
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel, read_csv
import openpyxl as px
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook, cell
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows


a = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\45050393\Documents\libro_vacio.xlsm", keep_vba = True)
df = pd.DataFrame({1 : [23, 34, 56, 78, 89, 12, 48]})
print(df)
ws = a.active
hoja_a_marcar = a.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
startcol = ws["H2":"H8"]
hoja_a_marcar.cell(row = 3, column = 4).value 

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False, header = False):
    for rows in startcol:
          ws.append(r)

print("HECHO")
a.save(filename= r"C:\Users\45050393\Documents\libro_vacio.xlsm")
```